# Pre written text into textarea

Tags: textarea

I want to make text area, where always is pre written text, and that piece of text is located at the end, and it wouldn't be possible to delete. For example, you write answer here, and at the end, right side of cursor, is text "This is end of my answer".

And when you POST it, it displays your written text and "This is end of my answer" at the end.

I know, that I can attach this text easily after posting it, but it must be displayed, and anyone could see it.

I need javascript/jQuery solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text to the right side of the cursor, that moves as you type is really annoying and zero-usable. However, if you want something like that I would suggest putting a background image on the textarea with the text you want. It will be static and none will be able to edit it, and at the same time will always see it.

Comment: But that text, what do you write, is covering that background image. And probably only few people would understand it, that nothing must be written.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="myinput" name="myinput" type="text" value="Text_Ends_Here" /></input>​​

$("input[name=myinput]").click(function()
    {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        currentValue = currentValue.replace("Text_Ends_Here", "");
        $(this).val(currentValue);
    }
);
$("input[name=myinput]").focusout(function()
    {
        var currentValue = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(currentValue + ' Text_Ends_Here');
    }
);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gXvLB/95/

Answer (score 0):

You can position the required text over textarea using positioning.